# Java Android Eclipse: R Classes disappear

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I've got a strange problem with R Classes in Java Eclipse (There are two R Classes, one in com.nameProject e one in android.support-v7). Well, when I add an ImageButton to my project, apperently everything is alrigt, my project doesn't take over any errors. But when I export my project (I create APK), **R Classes disappear from my project ON THEIR OWN**! So, the exporting fails and my project hasn't got anymore R Classes and it is incorrect...How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Exit eclipse ide and start it again. Then do clean and rebuild the project.

Comment: try to clean and rebuild the project, this should get the R classes regenerated. btw, ADT was announced dead by Google, consider switching to Android Studio

Comment: But why do R Classes disappear when I export my project after adding ImageButton?

Comment: Because there is some error in some of your resource files. Either being a wrong syntax in an xml file or an invalid character in a file name.

Comment: Why doesn't my project show me these errors?